# Web Crawler in Python: find tags values

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have to develop a Python crawler, but I barely know the language, so I'm having a lot of trouble. I got this model:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider (scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes'
    ]
    download_delay = 1.5

    def parse (self, response):
        for quote in response.css ('. q-question-body'):
            yield {
                'questions': quote.css ('. q-question-enunciation span :: text'). extract_first (),
                'answers': quote.css ('. q-item-enum :: text'). extract_first (),
    
            }
        link_next = response.css ('a.q-next a :: attr ("href")'). extract_first ()
        if link_next:
            yield scrapy.Request (response.urljoin (link_next))
```

Which is generating this .csv: http://cnessimples.com.br/arquivos/arquivo.csv

From that url: https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes

I need to get the questions and the answers for each question, this on every page of the site. I don't know how to do it in Python! If you can help me, I am very grateful.

P.S: The code is working, it just isn't working properly. The result can be seen in the .csv file. I need the questions and all the answers to each question. That on every page.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in HTML and variables.

Comment: put code again in question and use special button `{}` (or `Ctrl+K`) to correctly format it - code with wrong indentations is useless.

Comment: I don't know if using spaces in CSS is good ideas because with some spaces CSS may means something different then without spaces.

Comment: in python you don't have to use spaces between function's name and `()`, and between `.` and function's name. It makes code unreadable for other people. See also [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.orgdev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: The code is working, it just isn't working properly. The result can be seen in the .csv file. I need the questions and all the answers to each question. That on every page.

Comment: if you want all answers for question then DON'T use `extract_first()` but `extract()`

Comment: but first you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables - ie. `print( quote )`. You could also use `len()` to check how many elements you get with CSS selectors. You could also print `response.url` to see on which page you get this qestion and answers - maybe it use wrong URLS. Simply: you should debug your code and `print()` is primitive but simple method for debuging.

Comment: Ok. I do that and then I say if it worked.

Comment: I tried to run code but `CloudFlare` is blocking my access to your page so I can't test CSS selectors and I can't help you more.

Comment: I managed to extract the questions and answers and generated a file with the correct formatting ... But only on the first page!

Comment: We still need to pull data from the other pages.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get in `link_next` and `response.urljoin(link_next)` - maybe it can't find url to other page or it gets always the same url without `?page=...`. Simply: first use `print()` to debug code.

Comment: url format: https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes?page=1
Maybe I need a loop, increasing + 1 at the end of the url. How do I do?

Comment: for fist page you should get `link_next` with `?page=2`, not with `?page=1` - and this can be your probelm - first page gives you link to the same first page - so you have wrong CSS. And correct code should work without manual increasing `+1`

Comment: as for me it should be `'a.q-next::attr("href")'` - all your spaces in CSS selectors are only missleading. Beside CSS without space `a::attr(..)` and with space `a ::attr(..)` can mean different objects in HTML.

Comment: I managed to get the value of the other pages. However, only until page 31. At the prompt, the error message is: "status code is not handled or not allowed"

Comment: first you should check in real web browser if portal has more pages. You could also check what will happend when you open page bigger then 31 - maybe it will send page with different status then 200. OR maybe portal has complex sercure system for blocking bots/scripts/hackers/spamers - and then you may need much more complex code for this. You may have to buy Proxy Servers to send requests with different IP addresses.

Comment: The site goes to page 99. "OR maybe portal has complex sercure system for blocking bots/scripts/hackers/spamers" This is what is my fear. I'll see. Thank you very much for your attention!